# Comparing XML files using python scripting

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

There are 2 XML files and need to compare these two XMLS to verify that data is same or not. Now book id is not in same sequence in both the XMLs. but script should be able compare these 2 XMLs based on book id. can someone help me in this?

Output: Data is same in both XML files.

text1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <cool_number>QWZ5671</cool_number>
         <price>39.5</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX986</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Nay</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

text2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>      
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Comment: As StackOverflow is not a code writing service, please edit the code of your attempt to solve this problem into your question as a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from lxml import etree

root_1 = etree.parse('test1.xml').getroot()
root_2 = etree.parse('test2.xml').getroot()

d1, d2 = [], []
for node in root_1.findall('.//catalog_item'):
    for x in node.iter():
        if x.attrib:
            d1.append(x.attrib.values()[0])
        if x.text.strip():
            d1.append(x.text.strip())

for node in root_2.findall('.//catalog_item'):
    for x in node.iter():
        if x.attrib:
            d2.append(x.attrib.values()[0])
        if x.text.strip():
            d2.append(x.text.strip())

print('Data is same in both XML files') if set(d1) == set(d2) else print('Data is different in both XML files')
```

**Another method**

It will store witch properties are  which are different in a dictionary.

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict

root_1 = etree.parse('test1.xml').getroot()
root_2 = etree.parse('test2.xml').getroot()

d1, d2 = [], []
for node in root_1.findall('.//catalog_item'):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
        if x.attrib:
            item[x.attrib.keys()[0]].append(x.attrib.values()[0])
        if x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
    d1.append(dict(item))

for node in root_2.findall('.//catalog_item'):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
        if x.attrib:
            item[x.attrib.keys()[0]].append(x.attrib.values()[0])
        if x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
    d2.append(dict(item))

d1 = sorted(d1, key = lambda x: x['item_number'])
d2 = sorted(d2, key = lambda x: x['item_number'])

res_dict = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in zip(d1, d2):
    for key1, key2 in zip(x.keys(), y.keys()):
        if key1 == key2 and sorted(x[key1]) != sorted(y[key2]):
            res_dict[x['item_number'][0]].append({key1: list(set(x[key1]) ^ set(y[key2]))})

print('Data is same in both XML files') if res_dict == {} else print('Data is different in both XML files \n', dict(res_dict))
```

Comment: I have updated the correct xml files. I used your code by placing .//catalog_item instead of  .//xs:complexity and it is working fine but for the differences in these 2 tags catalog_item and size. If there is any difference in any of these tags like item_number, price or color_swatch then it is not finding the differences.

Comment: can you share the example you tested

Comment: I have updated both XMLs in my questions with different price value 39.5 in test1.xml. Difference was not found

Comment: just one weird thing noticed surprisingly that if I change from red to rd or re in test2. xml then it is not stating that difference but If I change anything else in test2.xml or in test1.xml including red word also then working fine

Comment: Thanks @komatiraju032 - I have been really trying hard to find the item# for that value which has mismatch. went through all the functions in lxml but still couldn't find any function to find the tag of an attribute.. like if there is diff coming for price 39.5 then it should tell item# also

Comment: @AbhinandanMehandiratta I have updated the answer. and i have added  `res_dict` dictionary it will store all the differences with `item_number` as key

Comment: Sir, sorry to reach out to you again for last time help... differences are getting jumbled from both the files like in test1.xml, there are 5 differences Burundy, Nay, 39.5, RRX986 and one extra tag is added <cool_number> but result is coming like {'RRX986': [{'item_number': ['RRX9856', 'RRX986']}, {'color_swatch': ['Burgundy', 'Burundy', 'Navy', 'Nay']}]} - it has jumbled differences so confused like which file has what differences.Also it is not detecting difference of new tag in test1.xml and difference of 39.5 after this new tag. Updated test1.xml

Comment: @AbhinandanMehandiratta it will work if each file has same number of tags only

Comment: @ komatiraju032 - Hey any idea if there is no value in between the tags <item_number></item_number> then it is telling 'nonetype' has no attribute 'strp' any idea, how to resolve that and we can have differences of blank values also